# Midlets execution problem

Tags: java, java-me, sdk, midlet

Using Java ME Platform SDK 3.0.

I open a new project and it is executed, but if i try to do one since new project>midlet this is create with hello world and this work but if i build the code in a class >new project>class.. and i write extends midlet implements command listener amm it doesn't work am dont get any bug and if i copy all my code and i paste it in a "new project>midlet" and i delete all it has and i paste my code, it does work mmm always and when the name was for default "HelloMidlet" i just watch two things...

INSTALL APPLICATION 
(if i open it it has : enter a website to install)
MANAGE CERTIFICATE AUTHORITIES

i repet if i let the default name "hellomidlet" it does work (with my self code) but if i change this name it doesn't work..

*** Error ***
A problem occured during deploying application from http://127.0.0.1:51612/MobileApplication2.jad
Reason:
Corrupt JAR, error while reading: hello/HelloMIDlet.class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you likely just have to set the MIDlet class name in the project settings...

Go into the Application Descriptor -> MIDlet settings, and make sure the classname there matches the name of your class that extends MIDlet.